# R raster() throwing file not found error despite try()

Tags: r, try-catch, lapply, raster

I have list of filepaths, that will be used as an input list for an `lapply()` with a custom function. That custom function does a couple things, mainly creates a raster object and pulls data from it.

One thing I cannot seem to get around, is that some of my filepaths are bad(they do not contain the other folders to parse). Normally I just add `try()` to the function that is erroring out, in order to make the script continue processing the next filepath on my list.

Here, it doesn't seem to work.
'''

```
imported_raster <- try(raster(files))
```

'''

returns...

```
Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 

Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not exist)
```

Hoping someone may know why I cannot get the `try()` to work when wrapped around `raster()`. If I just run `raster()` against 1 filepath with the file present, it works. `raster()` throws the same error I get from `lapply` with `raster()`, when I feed in a filepath that doesn't contain the data.

This makes me believe it is truly erroring out because of the file being missing, but I do not understand why `try()` cant deal with that.

In the end -- I just need `lapply` to continue to the next filepath instead of stopping.

Comment: This change still throws the same error, and the code doesn't move to my next file. Any idea why it is not moving to the next filepath when it errors here?

Comment: Also wanted to mention, I think all silent=TRUE does, is hide the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

Needed to wrap the entire function, that contains the raster(), with try().

literally...

```
repeat_finder <- function(files) try({
  message("Loading ", files)
  imported_raster <- raster(files)
  BLAH BLAH BLAH
  })
```

Comment: What is `BLAH BLAH BLAH` supposed to represent? If it isn't actually code, perhaps you should remove it from your answer.

Comment: I would do `try( repeat_finder()  )`